# Integration of periodic function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $a$ a T-periodic function. It is obvious that we have
$$n\int\limits_0^T a (s) = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 1} {\int\limits_{iT}^{(i + 1)T} a (s)ds} $$
I want to estimate the following quantity$$\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 1} {\int\limits_{ir}^{(i + 1)r} a (s)ds} $$
with $r$ is different of $T$ . Is there any possible simplifications ?
thank you.

Comment: Well, you can rewrite the integration up to $T \lfloor nr/T \rfloor$, but after that there is nothing to be done at this level of generality.

Comment: thank you Ian..